# Bidirectional Forwarding Detection (BFD) pcaps

Tags: wireshark, pcap

can someone help me with find some BFD Protocol wireshark pcaps?
i found only those three : http://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures , and i need some more.

thanks!.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It's good the read how to ask questions. Please include what you have tried and wat failed (-> http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For curiosity I type the topic to a internet search portal and find some interesting papers. Would this help?

Answer (score 0):

```
bfd-raw-auth-simple.pcap
bfd-raw-auth-md5.pcap
bfd-raw-auth-sha1.pcap
VC-Flapping-20090106v1_SMALL.pcap
BFD-testpacket
```

I believe the above files should be available as files attached to bug reports at bugs.wireshark.org and are alleged to contain BFD frames.

The first three are those in the sample captures. The other two may be of use.

You can find the actual bug to which a file is attached by selecting Search on bugs.wireshark.org and then doing a "custom search" under the "Not So Simple Search" tab.

Notes:

1. Use "Attachment Filename" "contains the string" >filename<
2. Make sure that *no* alternatives under "Resolution" are selected. (Control-click will deselect a selected entry).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the BFD implementation OpenBFDD from https://github.com/dyninc/OpenBFDD and generate your own pcaps.